# XmlTextReader/XmlNodeType namespace could not be found, how to fix?

Tags: c#, xmlnode, xmltextreader

My errors are in C# and idk why its telling me that `XmlTextReader` namespace could not be found. And I have to same error with `XmlNodeType` saying that it could not be found. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Updater
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string downloadUrl = " ";
    Version newVersion = null;
    string xmlUrl = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
    XmlTextReader reader = null; //The error here says that XmlTextReader could not be found
    try
    {
        reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlUrl);
        reader.MoveToContent();
        string elementName = " ";
        if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "EastPerlUpdater")) //XmleNodeType is another error that shows saying doesnt exist in current context, but its all over the place!!
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) //Again with the XmlNodeType error, and so on.
                {
                    elementName = reader.Name;
                }

                else
                {
                    if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) && (reader.HasValue))
                    {
                        switch(elementName)
                        {
                            case "version":
                            newVersion = new Version(reader.Vaule);
                            break;
                            case "url":
                            downloadUrl = reader.Vaule();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Environment.Exit(1);

    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();
    }
    Version applicationVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    if (applicationVersion.CompareTo(newVersion) < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Version " + newVersion.Major + "." + newVersion.Minor + "." + newVersion.Build + "A new version of East Perl Hub is available, want to download? Y/N");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (userInput == "Y")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(downloadUrl);
        }

        else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This app is up to date");
    }

    }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure **System.Xml** is included as a reference in your project and you added the correct using statement for it.

Comment: Well i'll be damned, Idk how I missed it. Thank you so much!